# access cascading dictionaries of unknown number

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have a dictionary

```
dict={'a':{'b':1}}
```

I use

```
dict['a']['b']
```

to access the '1'.  But if my dict is a cascading set of dictionaries of unknown number (i.e., `dict={'a':{'b':{'c':{'d':...}...{'?':1}}...})`, how can I loop through dict to access the end value?

I've been attempting to loop through dict, building a string each time through to get `"['a']['b']['c']..."` and use this string with `eval()`, but I can't figure out how to utilize `eval()` with dictionary access.

I want to do something like this pseudocode:

```
x="['a']['b']['c']"
eval(dict[x])
```

in order to get the value of

```
dict['a']['b']['c']
```

If anybody has any other ideas, please share.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short:

```
>>> dct = {"a": {"b": {"c": 1}}}
>>> reduce(dict.get, ["a", "b", "c"], dct)
1
```

## `reduce` and `dict.get` allowing "keys" like ["a", "b", "c"]

Having a dictionary `dct`:

```
>>> dct = {"a": {"b": {"c": 1}}}
```

we can access deeper levels by `get`:

```
>>> dct.get("a")
{'b': {'c': 1}}
>>> dct.get("a").get("b")
{'c': 1}
>>> dct.get("a").get("b").get("c")
1
```

`reduce` can apply repeatedly a method on previous result:

```
>>> reduce(dict.get, ["a", "b", "c"], dct)
1
```

## Concept of deepkey

If the above one line method does not seem suitable to your needs, you may create access function:

```
>>> def getdeep(dct, deepkey):
...     return reduce(dict.get, deepkey, dct)
...
```

test if with `deepkey` being list of keys:

```
>>> getdeep(dct, ["a", "b"])
{'c': 1}
```

going any level (assuming, the values do exist there)

```
>>> getdeep(dct, ["a", "b", "c"])
1
```

working for any iterable, incl hashable tuple:

```
>>> getdeep(dct, ("a", "b", "c"))
1
```

and you may start using variables representing deep address of a value:

```
>>> deepkey = ("a", "b", "c")
>>> getdeep(dct, deepkey)
1
```

### `setdeep` using `reduce`

If we want to use `reduce` to modify value pointed to by `deepkey`, we can do it, but in two steps:

1. get the deepest  dictionary (this means not the value `1`, but `{"c": 1}`
2. set to "c" key of this deep dictionary the new value

On console it looks like:

```
>>> reduce(dict.get, deepkey[:-1], dct)
{"c": 1}
>>> reduce(dict.get, deepkey[:-1], dct)[deepkey[-1]] = 99
>>> dct
{"a": {"b": {"c": 99}}}
```

So the `setdeep` could be written as:

```
def setdeep(dct, deepkey, val):
    getdeep(dct, deepkey[:-1])[deepkey[-1]] = val
```

Comment: Thank you for the information.  Is there a way to utilize reduce() with the dictionary update() function?  E.g., if I wanted to update the value of 'c': changing 1 to 2.

Comment: @user1320737 Yes, it could be done. I added `setdeep` to my answer. Anyway, it is not using `dict.update`, but uses direct assignment.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
def get(d, keys):
    for key in keys:
        d = d[key]
    return d

d={'a':{'b':1}}
get(d, ['a', 'b'])
```